# Install Force.com IDE 2

Tags: force.com, vs-code

From the below link I came to know they will not provide further update on Force.com IDE 2 tool and no downloads are available after May 3, 2018.

> The Force.com IDE 2 beta release has been discontinued. We are not
>   providing future releases of this tool, and no downloads are available
>   after May 3, 2018. You cannot access the Force.com IDE 2 Developer
>   Guide as of April 23, 2018. We recommend using [Salesforce Extensions
>   for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) instead.

What might be the reason for this and why they are promoting Microsoft's VS Code IDE?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_ide2.meta/sfdx_ide2/sfdx_ide2_get_started_download_install.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of factors for promoting [VS Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/02/salesforce-extensions-vs-code.html):

> - It is highly customizable and is cross-platform.
> - Salesforce is moving towards Open standards, and VS Code serves that perfectly where third-party developers from different
>     environments can come-in and develop the tools needed as per their
>     skills and expertise on Force.com Platform.
> - The Salesforce extensions provide features such as code completion, syntax highlighting, Apex live debugging, and more for the Lightning
>     Platform.
> - By choosing VS code, Salesforce focus is now on the quality rather than editor issues.